# Action bar in anchorlayout - KIVY. python

Tags: python, android-actionbar, kivy

My goal is to make add these 3 buttons to an actionbar on the top of the screen as seen in the screenshot, please help.

.kv file

```
AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: 'center'
    anchor_y: 'top'
    BoxLayout: 
        padding: 30
        size_hint: 1, .1
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            text: 'Back'
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'mainpage'                    
        TextInput:
            text: 'Search'                       
        Button:
            text: 'Fav'
```

**Fav and back button will later be changed to icons, and search will be a dropdown**

.py file

```
class MainPage(Screen):
    pass
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEVmD.png)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a relative layout inside your box layout:

```
BoxLayout: 
    padding: 30
    size_hint: 1, .1
    orientation: 'horizontal'

    RelativeLayout:

        Button:
            text: 'Back'
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.1, 'center_y': 0.5}
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'mainpage'  

        TextInput:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
            text: 'Search'                       

        Button:
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.9, 'center_y': 0.5}
            text: 'Fav'
```